# How to align a text link next to an image link in a table row with inline styles only?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm having an issue aligning text and an image link next to each other in a  table row. The image keeps drifting up and down. I've tried various align middle and display block styles with no luck. I am limited to only having CSS inline and trying to display properly across different devices and desktop email clients. The posted code is a nested table that I can not get the elements to align with each other. Viewing the code in the browser, for the most part, displays correctly. But once the code is in Outlook and other programs the image drifts within the row.

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsbZR.png)

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<td height="100%" align="left">
<a href="tel:5555555555" style="font-size: 13px;">555-555-5555 | </a>
</td>
<td height="100%" align="left">
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" style="font-size: 13px">stackoverflow.com  | </a>
</td>
<td height="100%" align="left" font-size="13px" style="font-size: 13px; line-height:100%;">
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/stack-overflow/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/hf2gbC1/in.png" style="margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 2px" alt="Stack Overflow LinkedIn" width="11" height="11"></a>
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Show us some example code, and some screenshots of a) the intended result and b) the current wrong appearance.

Comment: Added code example and screenshot.

Comment: I'm not clear if that screenshot is the way you want it or the way you *don't* want it. It'd be nice if you could show both. You can try setting `valign` on the table cells or `vertical-align` in CSS, perhaps, or breaking the table cell into two.

Comment: Screenshot is not what I would like to display.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple and when tested with Litmus it has consistent results across all email clients. I set the font size, line-height and image size to 13px. Since they were all equal, it made it easier to align. I didn't put an align on the table because it should default to middle-align. On the image I placed `vertical-align: -2px;` Outlook has buggy support when it comes to using values like `middle`, but not with number values. in the style sheet and added `display: inline-block;`. I placed everything in one `<td>`.

With Gmail, Apple, IOS, Android and other email clients, everything remains consistent. With Outlook, it shifts about a pixel.

I also added `text-decoration: none;` to the hrefs to clean up the look a bit.

```
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin: 0;">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 13px; text-decoration: none;">
      <a href="tel:5555555555" style="font-size: 13px; text-decoration: none;">555-555-5555</a> | 
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" style="font-size: 13px; text-decoration: none;">stackoverflow.com</a>  | 
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/stack-overflow/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/hf2gbC1/in.png" style="vertical-align: -2px;" alt="United States Appraisals LinkedIn" width="13" height="13"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

writing html for email is like a trip back to the [90ies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)!

if you wrap all your `<td>` inside a tabelrow `<tr>` and set it's valign to bottom,

just run the code snippet:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr height="20px" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFCC" >
    <td height="100%" align="left">
      <a href="tel:5555555555" style="font-size: 13px;">555-555-5555 | </a>
    </td>
    <td height="100%" align="left">
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" style="font-size: 13px">stackoverflow.com  | </a>
    </td>
    <td height="100%" align="left" font-size="13px" style="font-size: 13px; line-height:100%;">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/stack-overflow/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/hf2gbC1/in.png" style="margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 2px" alt="United States Appraisals LinkedIn" width="11" height="11"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `valign="bottom"` for all `td`s, and in addition add some `padding-bottom` to the `img` tag to correct the slight vertical offset between text and image (actually only 1px in this particular example):

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<td height="100%" align="left" valign="bottom">
<a href="tel:5555555555" style="font-size: 13px;">555-555-5555 | </a>
</td>
<td height="100%" align="left" valign="bottom">
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" style="font-size: 13px">stackoverflow.com  | </a>
</td>
<td height="100%" align="left" font-size="13px" style="font-size: 13px; line-height:100%;" valign="bottom">
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/stack-overflow/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/hf2gbC1/in.png" style="margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 2px; padding-bottom: 1px;" alt="United States Appraisals LinkedIn" width="11" height="11"></a>
</td>
</table>
```